# Django raw query cursor error

Tags: sql, django

The following code gives me an error

```
from django.db import connection
cursor = connection.cursor()
```

Error message:

```
Undefined variable from import: cursor
```

I have Django 1.2.5 installed. How can a resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: That's not an error. That's a PyDev information message.

Comment: You are right! I am able to run the script without a problem. PyDev shows it as an error. Thanks Daniel

Comment: please, post your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was just a PyDev information message as Daniel pointed out. I am able to run the script without modifying anything.